# ShaderMaterial with shadows doesn't compile after threejs v0.118.0

Tags: three.js, glsl, webgl

Followed this example but the vertex shader doesn't compile after threejs v0.118.0:
https://codesandbox.io/s/shader-light-shadow-experiments-forked-5e14lh

You can test this in codesandbox by selecting different three versions in the dependencies section on the sidebar.
Error msg in printed in console:

```
THREE.WebGLProgram: shader error:  0 35715 false gl.getProgramInfoLog Vertex shader is not compiled.
THREE.WebGLShader: gl.getShaderInfoLog() vertex
ERROR: 0:197: 'transformedNormal' : undeclared identifier
ERROR: 0:197: 'inverseTransformDirection' : no matching overloaded function found
ERROR: 0:197: '=' : dimension mismatch
ERROR: 0:197: '=' : cannot convert from 'const mediump float' to 'highp 3-component vector of float'
```

Checked the migration guide for r117 -> r118 but could not figure out how to fix it.
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Migration-Guide#r117--r118

Comment: Please consider to paste the error you got and initial vertex shader code into your post. It will help to find the answer for this and similar problems to other users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error is:

```
ERROR: 0:199: 'transformedNormal' : undeclared identifier
ERROR: 0:199: 'inverseTransformDirection' : no matching overloaded function found
```

To relsolve it, you need to add normal definition to your vertex shader. The following code fixes your case.

```
    #include <common>
    #include <fog_pars_vertex>
    #include <shadowmap_pars_vertex>
    void main() {
      #include <begin_vertex>
      #include <beginnormal_vertex>     // Defines objectNormal
      #include <project_vertex>
      #include <worldpos_vertex>
      #include <defaultnormal_vertex>   // Defines transformedNormal
      #include <shadowmap_vertex>
      #include <fog_vertex>
    }
```